# Right alignment in flalign environment

Tags: math-mode, alignment, mathtools, flalign

I'm compiling a list of math exercises with solutions: I would like to left-align the exercise numbers and to right-align the results. I have tried the flalign* environment, but it doesn't work well. This is a working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{flalign*}
1) &\; \frac{3}{4}x^2-\frac{8}{3}=0 & \left[ \pm\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{2} \right]&\\ 
2) &\; 3x-\sqrt{3}x^2=0 & \left[0,\sqrt{3}\right]&\\
3) &\; \frac{1}{25}x^2+\frac{2}{5}x+1=0 & \left[ -5\text{ doppia}\right]&\\
4) &\; -\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{7}{6}x+2=0 & \left[-\frac{4}{3}, 6\right]&\\
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

This is the result: the square parentheses are not right-aligned very well. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean in "the square parentheses are not right-aligned very well"? You want the four pair of square parentheses having the same width?

Comment: I want them right-aligned, they are not now.

Answer (score 2):

The width of `\left[ \right]` brackets automatically changes depending on the height of the contents. You must use `\vphantom{}` command with some argument that is larger than any argument of the right-aligned contents

For example, you might want to use `\vphantom{\frac{1}{4}x^2}` in any place inside the contents of the brackets. For a neat way, it is better to define a new command

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
        
\begin{document}
    
\begin{flalign*}
    1) &\; \frac{3}{4}x^2-\frac{8}{3}=0 & \left[ \pm\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{2} \largevPhantom \right]\\ 
    2) &\; 3x-\sqrt{3}x^2=0 & \left[0,\sqrt{3} \largevPhantom \right]\\
    3) &\; \frac{1}{25}x^2+\frac{2}{5}x+1=0 & \left[ -5\text{ doppia} \largevPhantom \right]\\
    4) &\; -\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{7}{6}x+2=0 & \left[-\frac{4}{3}, 6 \largevPhantom \right]\\
\end{flalign*}


\end{document}
```

Another option (does not use `\vphantom`) is to use `bigg[ \bigg]`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
        
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
    1) &\; \frac{3}{4}x^2-\frac{8}{3}=0 & \bigg[ \pm\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{2}  \bigg]\\ 
    2) &\; 3x-\sqrt{3}x^2=0 & \bigg[0,\sqrt{3} \bigg]\\
    3) &\; \frac{1}{25}x^2+\frac{2}{5}x+1=0 & \bigg[ -5\text{ doppia} \bigg]\\
    4) &\; -\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{7}{6}x+2=0 & \bigg[ -\frac{4}{3}, 6 \bigg]\\
\end{flalign*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I see. In this way, all the brackets will be the same size. Does it exist a way to align brackets with different vertical sizes? Perhaps substituting flalign with another environment?

Comment: It would also be good to use `bigg` for brackets

Answer (score 1):

If there's something I hate, it's exercises with the solutions at the right margin. ;-)

The brackets *are* aligned, the only problem is that they have different sizes. You can alleviate the problem by using smaller ones, for instance, and separating them vertically a bit more. Anyway, `flalign` is not the right choice to begin with.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fixcmex} % important if you use lmodern with math
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide,label=\arabic*),itemsep=1ex]
\item  $\displaystyle\frac{3}{4}x^2-\frac{8}{3}=0$\hfill
       $\displaystyle\Bigl[\, \pm\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{2} \,\Bigr]$

\item $\displaystyle 3x-\sqrt{3}x^2=0$\hfill
      $\displaystyle\bigl[\, 0,\sqrt{3} \,\bigr]$

\item $\displaystyle\frac{1}{25}x^2+\frac{2}{5}x+1=0$\hfill
      $\displaystyle[\, -5\text{ doppia} \,]$

\item $\displaystyle-\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{7}{6}x+2=0$\hfill
      $\displaystyle\Bigl[\, -\frac{4}{3}, 6 \,\Bigr]$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I added thin spaces at either side in order to separate the solution from the delimiters (which are not really mathematical delimiters) and avoided `\left` and `\right` preferring `\Big` size when fractions are involved.

[image]

Comment: But the brackets are not aligned: notice the third one (I didn't use the enumerate environment because I use another macro to keep track of the exercise number).